# Build automation of UNIX / Linux packages

Tags: open-source, c++, c

Is there any simple build tool that could be used for build automation of multiple UNIX software packages for embedded world.

I know there is Buildroot & Yocto, but both of them build Linux systems from scratch. I don't indent to build the kernel, only user-space libs and applications.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What kind and what level of build automation? What kind of packages? For what intended use?

Comment: Also, your question isn't qualified enough: What license? What price range? On what hardware should it run? What OSes? Native code or interpreted or don't-care? What are some necessary and desirable specific features? etc.